# How should I fix this code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to sort an array of people objects. The class looks like this.

```
Person
-------
name
phone
```

I have an NSMutableArray filled with these objects. I want to sort this array by the name of each person object.

This is the code I tried.

```
NSSortDescriptor  *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES];
[personArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: desc]];
```

It doesn't work. How can it be changed to work?

Comment: I know an answer has already been posted and it is most likely correct, but as a general word of advice:  "it doesn't work" is not very helpful.  You need to say what exactly is broken.  For example "personArray remains unsorted" would have a totally different answer to "getting the exception NSCFString does not respond to -sortedArrayUsingDescriptors".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're aware that `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns a new (sorted) array, correct?  If you want to sort the array in-place, then you need to make sure that `personArray` is an `NSMutableArray` and use its `sortUsingDescriptors:` method.

**edit**

Perhaps taking a look at the two methods will be more beneficial:

```
-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:];
-[NSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:];
```

The first one starts with an adjective and a noun.  The adjective describes the noun.  The noun indicates that it is the return value.  Since the noun is "array", it would make sense that the return value of the method is an `NSArray`.  Since the adjective is "sorted", we can therefore assume that the returned array will be in some sort of order (the order being specified by the "using" the "descriptors").

The second one starts with a verb.  Since a verb is an action word, we can deduce that this is actually a behavioral method that will modify the receiver itself.  Since the verb is "sort", we can therefore assume that the receiver will be in some sort of order after the method has completed.

Other "method pairs" that follow this pattern:

- `-[NSString stringByAppendingString:]` and `-[NSMutableString appendString:]`
- `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` and `-[NSMutableArray filterUsingPredicate:]`
- `-[NSCharacterSet invertedSet]` and `-[NSMutableCharacterSet invert]`
- ...and many others

Since you're using the first method (`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`), you *must* retrieve the return value of the method; otherwise you're doing all this work for nothing.  If you want to sort the array "in place" (ie, modify the receiver directly and *not* be given a new `NSArray`), then `personArray` *must* be an `NSMutableArray`, and you *must* use the `sortUsingDescriptors:` method.

Comment: Isn't that what I did? personArray is an NSMutableArray of person objects. I'm trying to sort by the name inside the person object.

Comment: @awakeFromnib: No that's not what you did. You called `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` instead of `sortArrayUsingDescriptors:` ... yours starts with "sorted", his suggestion starts with "sort".

Comment: to clarify imaginaryboy's comment: sortedArray... creates a new array, leaving the original unsorted. sortArray... sorts the source array.

Comment: I changed it to sortArray and got a warning message that NSMutableArray might not respond to that. Then when I ran the program it crashed.

Comment: @awakeFromNib edited answer for more info; also, apologies for typo-ing a method name.