# NSSortDescriptor not sorting my NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSMutableArray that has NSDictionaries in it.  I found a question on SO, and am using this code to sort this NSMutableArray:

**NSMutableArray**

```
{
    data =         {
   etc... (for length)
    };
    number = 1;
},
{
    data =         {
       etc... (for length)
    };
    number = 3;
},
{
    data =         {
       etc... (for length)
    };
    number = 4;
},
{
    data =         {
       etc... (for length)
    };
    number = 2;
}
```

This array goes up to 80 sub Dictionaries.

**NSSortDescriptor**

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"number"  ascending:YES];
[NSMUTABLEARRAYVAR sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
 NSMutableArray *test;            
 test = [NSMUTABLEARRAYVAR copy];
```

When I NSLog "test" I get the same order as NSMUTABLEARRAYVAR???

I would appreciate any help in solving this issue, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I fix this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852464/how-should-i-fix-this-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingDescriptors%3a) does not sort the array in place. It returns a newly-sorted array.

[`sortUsingDescriptors`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingDescriptors%3a) does an in-place sort.

Comment: That works!! Except I found an issue - it goes 1, 10, 11, 12 and then on every double digit number ending with 9, it goes back to single - 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,3,30 etc... any idea?

Comment: The "number" properties are being sorted as strings. If they are `NSString`, can you change your dictionary to store them as `NSNumber`? Otherwise I think you will need a comparator or a selector to sort the strings as though they were numbers.

Comment: Your sort needs to be based on a `localizedStandardCompare:` - this will place let's say 10 after 9 instead of after 1